# Was my game activated twice on the same Uplay account?

Tags: steam, ubisoft-connect

I created a uplay account a few years ago for my little brother. I sended him FarCry Primal as a steam gift last month, and it was activated on his uplay account, because he was logged in on it.

However, I also purchased the game on steam today and played it. But in the main menu it says 'Continue' and a savegame with 35% progress loads, even though I never played it before?

So I checked Uplay and noticed that I am still logged in to his account which I created for him a few years ago. So it seems that the game was registered twice to the same account!

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the problem. I signed in to my new Uplay account and started the game on Steam, then a message showed which asked me If I want to move the game to this account. Now it works!